# WPF привязка данных

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть пользовательский класс с двумя полями (заголовок и изображение,оба строки).Моя проблема в том,что при привязки данных отображается тип данных, а не сами привязанные данные.То есть, я хочу отобразить изображение и заголовок в listView. Подскажите,как можно этого добиться.

### код окна XAML

```
 <ListView x:Name = "listview" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Movies}" Margin="0,37,10,0">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding Image}"/>

                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                            <TextBlock Margin="5" FontSize="26" Text="{Binding Title}"/>

                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

### **код С#**

```
 public partial class MainMovie : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<MovieData> Movies { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<MovieData>();
    public ObservableCollection<MovieData> AllMovies { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<MovieData>();
  
    public MainMovie()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        foreach (var movie in LoadMovies())
        {
            AllMovies.Add(movie);
            Movies.Add(movie);
        }


    }
```

### **Класс MovieData:**

```
 public class MovieData
{
  
    public string Title
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public string Image 
    { 
        get; set;
    }

    public MovieData(string title, string image)
    {
        Title = title;
        Image = image;
    }
}
```

Comment: `с двумя полями` - привязка допускается **только** к публичным свойствам. Вообще, покажите класс `MovieData`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ добавила к вопросу.

Comment: Почему тогда про поля говорите, если в классе свойства...?) В любом случае, ваша проблема в том, что вы смешали в одну кучу несколько видов. Вы при помощи `ItemTemplate` задаете вид объекту, желая чтоб те вывелись просто в ряд, но также и пишете `GridViewColumn`, что подразумевает табличный вывод, где каждое свойство == своя колонка. Собственно, определитесь, что вам нужно. Если первое, то убирайте `GridViewColumn` (а лучше вовсе перейти на `ListBox` или `ItemsControl`) ; Если второе, то задавайте колонки (а-ля `<GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Title}" Header="Название" />`).